# Formatação do código da pergunta: incentivar um padrão?

Tags: debate

É comum que em uma pergunta seja colocado um trecho de código para mostrar o problema dela. Sabemos que um código mal formatado é mais difícil de entender, por isso tal importância.

E claro que como há vários estilos de formatação de código escolher um padrão para o não é uma boa ideia, mas porém poderíamos incentivar algumas sugestões que melhorariam o entendimento do código:

- O espaço horizontal disponível para a pergunta é em torno de 660px, logo evitar trechos com linhas que passem desse ponto, forçando barras de rolagem;
  Preferir indenizar com dois espaços, para aproveitar mais o espaço;
- Se o trecho de código é grande preferir inserir um link para o código, mas se há uma parte dele com maior importância para a questão então coloque-o no corpo dela;
  Ainda que digam "o código só se expande até 600px de altura": isso *pode* acabar incentivando a organização, por exemplo separando a marcação dos estilos e do código.

Comment: Observação: publiquei a pergunta sem terminar de editar, alguma coisa deu errado e ela foi ao ar. Mesmo assim ela já tem detalhes suficientes para ser respondida.

Answer (score 4):

## Barra de rolagem horizontal

Acho que devemos, sempre que possível, tentar remover essa barra de rolagem.
Pois isso facilita a leitura e compreensão do código.

Exemplificando em PHP, em vez de:

```
$args = array( 'numberposts' => -1, 'offset' => 0, 'orderby' => 'post_date', 'order' => 'DESC', 'post_type' => 'post', 'post_status' => 'publish' );
```

Teremos:

```
$args = array(
    'numberposts'     => -1,
    'offset'          => 0,
    'orderby'         => 'post_date',
    'order'           => 'DESC',
    'post_type'       => 'post',
    'post_status'     => 'publish' 
);
```

## Barra de rolagem vertical

A norma no Stack Exchange é que todo o material necessário deve estar contido na Pergunta, usando material de sites externos como ferramentas de apoio (demos, leitura extra se houver interesse).

Se o código for excessivamente longo, é quase certo que o autor da pergunta não tomou seu tempo para produzir um [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) *(Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example)*. Comentários solicitando a simplificação, votos negativos ou fechamento da Pergunta seriam as ações indicadas.

## Indentação

Quando não existe indentação ou quando ela faz a lógica difícil de entender, então devemos editar de acordo com os padrões de cada linguagem de programação.

## Estilo

Devemos evitar mudar o estilo. Pessoalmente prefiro:

```
function foo()
{
    bar();
}
```

Do que:

```
function foo(){
    bar();
}
```

Se o código foi escrito por alguém que segue um padrão organizado, não é admissível que um editor modifique o código por uma variação do seu gosto. Se fosse meu *post*, eu faria um *rollback* da edição (incorporando outras melhorias que o editor/a haja feito).